# Upserting into PostgreSQL while DST change causes error

Tags: postgresql, dst, upsert

I am trying to upsert into PostgreSQL this set of data:

```
INSERT INTO data_sensordata (sensor_id, timestamp, value, flag, tz_offset)
VALUES
    ('20', timestamp with time zone '2015-03-29 00:15:00+02:00', 0.0, '0', 7200),
    ('20', timestamp with time zone '2015-03-29 00:30:00+02:00', 0.0, '0', 7200),
    ('20', timestamp with time zone '2015-03-29 00:45:00+02:00', 0.0, '0', 7200),
    ('20', timestamp with time zone '2015-03-29 01:00:00+02:00', 0.0, '0', 7200),
    ('20', timestamp with time zone '2015-03-29 01:15:00+02:00', 0.0, '0', 7200),
    ('20', timestamp with time zone '2015-03-29 01:30:00+02:00', 0.0, '0', 7200),
    ('20', timestamp with time zone '2015-03-29 01:45:00+02:00', 0.0, '0', 7200),
    ('20', timestamp with time zone '2015-03-29 02:00:00+02:00', 0.0, '0', 7200),
    ('20', timestamp with time zone '2015-03-29 02:15:00+02:00', 0.0, '0', 7200),
    ('20', timestamp with time zone '2015-03-29 02:30:00+02:00', 0.0, '0', 7200),
    ('20', timestamp with time zone '2015-03-29 02:45:00+02:00', 0.0, '0', 7200),
    ('20', timestamp with time zone '2015-03-29 03:00:00+02:00', 0.0, '0', 7200),
    ('20', timestamp with time zone '2015-03-29 03:15:00+02:00', 0.0, '0', 7200),
    ('20', timestamp with time zone '2015-03-29 03:30:00+02:00', 0.0, '0', 7200),
    ('20', timestamp with time zone '2015-03-29 03:45:00+02:00', 0.0, '0', 7200),
    ('20', timestamp with time zone '2015-03-29 04:00:00+03:00', 0.0, '0', 10800)
ON CONFLICT (
    sensor_id,
    timestamp
    )
    DO UPDATE
    SET
        value = EXCLUDED.value,
        flag  = EXCLUDED.flag
```

This gives me:

`[21000] ERROR: ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE command cannot affect row a second time Hint: Ensure that no rows proposed for insertion within the same command have duplicate constrained values.`

The problem is (I think) because of the DST change in the last element (from +2 to +3).

Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: What is the type for the `timestamp` field in the table?

Comment: Assuming this data is from Greece (per your user profile), the duplicate data is actually the values from `2015-03-29 03:00:00+02:00` through  `2015-03-29 03:45:00+02:00`, because the start of DST was at 03:00.   If this is data from a sensor, then it should not have recorded timestamps in that range.  It should have gone from `2015-03-29 02:45:00+02:00` and the next reading 15 minutes later should have been `2015-03-29 04:00:00+03:00`.  So the question is: where did your data come from that it was collected with duplicate timestamps?

Comment: And yes - the actual conflict is because `2015-03-29 03:00:00+02:00` is the same point in time as `2015-03-29 04:00:00+03:00`.  In other words, they are both equivalent to `2015-03-29T01:00:00Z`.

Comment: Your input data seems to be incorrect, assuming the same instant of time is not supposed to be showing up multiple times.  Rather than cramming broken data into the database anyway, maybe you should figure out how to fix the source.

Comment: For reference, see https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/greece/athens?year=2015

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint, the data is given to me in a CSV file, not directly by the sensors but by a company which collects data. I can contact the data collector and ask some questions. What you say makes sense to me. Maybe their exporting process is wrong.

Comment: @jjanes, I am given this set of data, but I can contact the source. Maybe their data export process is wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @xpanta - Just a guess, but is it possible that their timestamps are created wrong?  For example, perhaps they meant that the date and time were in UTC, and tacked the offset on to the end?  That's incorrect formatting, because ISO 8601 and RFC 3339 both state that the date and time are the _local_ time, and the offset describes that local time.  But some folks get this wrong and record the UTC date and time with the local offset.  If so, that would explain the data.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint, I cannot know until I contact the company which collects the data. The tz_offset field I compute (from the TZ value of the datetime object) for my own reasons. The timestamps and the values are the only entries in their files

Comment: ...actually, never mind.  It wouldn't - because the transition is at the wrong time.  It would have to have the transition at 1:00 UTC.  So I'm not sure how they have this data.  Unless it's from some other time zone.